# How to derive Parameter Derivative within an FFT integral

Tags: options, parameter, integral

I have the following function (Carr-Madan) of which I am trying to take the derivative wrt $\theta$:

$c(k)=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-iuk}}{\alpha^2 + \alpha - u^2 + i(2\alpha+1)u} e^{\phi_T(u-(\alpha+1)i,\theta)} du$

Since the integration bounds are not dependent on $\theta$, according to the Leipniz integration rule, I derive the following:

$\frac{dc(k)}{d\theta}=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-iuk}}{\alpha^2 + \alpha - u^2 + i(2\alpha+1)u} \frac{d(e^{\phi_T(u-(\alpha+1)i,\theta)})}{d\theta} du$

$=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-iuk}}{\alpha^2 + \alpha - u^2 + i(2\alpha+1)u} e^{\phi_T(u-(\alpha+1)i,\theta)} \frac{d\phi_T(u-(\alpha+1)i,\theta)}{d\theta} du$

Essentially we can evaluate the term inside the integral of $c(k)$ and multiply such by $\frac{d\phi_T(u-(\alpha+1)i,\theta)}{d\theta}$. Then I use FFT to evaluate that the entire integral expression.

Now I evaluate this term numerically and get complete nonsense for the derivative term. I have already checked numerically if $\frac{d\phi_T(x,\theta)}{d\theta}$ is correct and used other programs (Mathematica) to check its correctness. Have I come to the derivative term correctly?